# Has Japan's "Special Secrecy Law" been condemned by the United Nations?

Tags: law, japan, civil-rights, united-nations

Has the [Act on the Protection of Specially Designated Secrets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Secrecy_Law) been condemned in any way by the [United Nations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations)? Or any expressed concerns by the United Nations?

Reference needed.
I haven't been able to find any solid reference coming from the United States themselves.

All I have found is [this submission](http://www.ccprcentre.org/doc/2014/06/INT_CCPR_CSS_JPN_17355_E.pdf) by the [Center for Civil and Political Rights](http://www.ccprcentre.org/):

> [...] We request that the United Nations Human Rights Committee (the “Committee”) express concern to the Japanese government concerning the enforcement of this Act [...]

And non-referenced articles like [this one](http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2014/12/11/japan-s-nasty-nazi-ish-elections.html) on [The Daily Beast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Daily_Beast):

> The election on December 14th isn’t about Japan’s oppressive (and **United Nations-condemned**) Designated Secrets Law which went into effect on the December 10, four days before the ballot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if it's strong enough to count as a condemnation, but they have ["expressed serious concern".](http://www.ohchr.org/EN/NewsEvents/Pages/DisplayNews.aspx?NewsID=14017&LangID=E)

Two independent experts have spoken about the *draft version* of the bill. One from a freedom of speech/expression angle:

> “Transparency is a core requirement for democratic governance,” the Special Rapporteur on freedom of expression, Frank La Rue, said. “The draft bill not only appears to establish very broad and vague grounds for secrecy but also include serious threats to whistle-blowers and even journalists reporting on secrets.”

While one looked at it from a public health angle:

> The Special Rapporteur on the right to health, Anand Grover, who visited Japan last year and studied the response to the disaster in Fukushima, underlined the need for to always ensure full transparency in emergency contexts: “Particularly in calamities, it is essential to ensure that the public is provided with consistent and timely information enabling them to make informed decisions regarding their health.”

I don't know if/how much the bill has changed in the year since these statements were made, or if they have any *current* concerns, since I haven't seen a more recent statement from anyone associated with the UN.